# math.SE traffic

Tags: support, statistics

It looks like the traffic is really high today, probably because of the introduction of hats.

I was wondering, is there a way to check statistics about the traffic on math.SE, and on the other SE websites?

Comment: Why do you say it looks like traffic is high today?

Comment: Simply because it looks like there are more questions and more votes than usual

Answer (score 8):

There are publicly visible statistics available on [Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/math.stackexchange.com). As SE uses the Quantcast tracker, they don't have to guess and this is actual traffic data.

You'll have to wait a bit though, the graphs are only updated later the next day.

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look at the [Alexa rankings](http://www.alexa.com/) for any site, but those aren't very good. Stackexchange keeps its own, more detailed data on traffic and usage, but this is not available to regular users.